# How to open or link to my addon preference pane from link in a page

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating an addon from which I display a page from the data/ resources. I would like to put in there a link to open the addon preferences page. Is it possible? How?

Thanks in advance,
Stefano

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely possible.

In depth reply here: [How to open an add-on's preference panel?](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=16276&sid=3cb16d38adb6a5ac7cf194974de48233)

to add link on your site make it dispatch custom event, catch that custom event in your addon and use the window the event came from and execute the for example:

```
Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').BrowserOpenAddonsMgr('addons://detail/%7Bd10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d%7D/preferences')
```

or on load of your website you can addEventListener to the link on your website. The addEventListener listener function will be in your addon.